# I can't change the text of textView from a DialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I'm facing this problem and don't have any idea how to solve it. It works inside the dialog class, but not in the activity class.

I tried all i found about this problem: creating the setter method, invoking the method after showing the dialog, the id is correct so idk.
This is the dialog class:

```
class CustomDialogFragment: DialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var textView: TextView
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        isCancelable = false
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.winner_dialog, container, false)
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.dialogtextView)
        return view
    }
    fun setTextViewText(winner: String) {
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            textView.text = winner
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I created an instance of this class and used it like this:

```
if(Check.checkForX(boxes)){
      dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "customDialog")
      if (firstPlayer != null) {
           dialog.setTextViewText(firstPlayer)
      }
}
```

P.S: the dialog box pops up, just the text in it is not changing. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sere you have access to activity in your setter method? Because if you wouldn't, the ?. call could prevent the text from setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's probably because you're trying to call this function immediately after [`dialog.show`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#show(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,java.lang.String)):

> `public void show(@NonNull FragmentManager manager, @Nullable String tag)`
>
> Display the dialog, adding the fragment to the given FragmentManager. **This is a convenience for explicitly creating a transaction, adding the fragment to it with the given tag, and committing it**.

And as [the `commit` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#commit()) explains:

> `public abstract int commit()`
>
> Schedules a commit of this transaction. **The commit does not happen immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be done the next time that thread is ready.**

So basically when you call `show`, you're requesting the dialog be shown - but it's not added yet! So it's not attached to its `Activity`, and this

```
activity?.runOnUiThread
```

won't run, because `activity` is *null* at this point.

---

The other issue is that [`onCreate` is called *after* `onAttach`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#onAttach(android.content.Context)) (i.e. after the `activity` is accessible) which means `onCreateView` hasn't run yet either, and you don't have a reference to `textView` to set text on. You basically can't call this function at all yet, even if you remove the activity reference.

You could update the function to store the current text value if you don't have `textView` yet, and set that text during `onCreateView` if you have it stored (deferring the task basically). This is useful if you're gonna need to update that text at different times, but if this is a one-shot setup thing, it would be easier to just set the text as a Fragment argument, and pull it out during `onCreateView` or whatever, like in the example [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#basic-dialog) (they're doing it in a `newInstance` method so the details are internal to the dialog's class - you just pass a string in as a parameter when you actually want an dialog object).

Comment: Thanks, it worked by allocating a new thread in the setter.